# Scatter map plot using plotly and Pandas won't display

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

Im currently doing a project for my CS class and I am analyzing a CVS file that has the electric vehicle population in Washington state. I have gotten most of the graph finished but I was attempting to make a Scatter map plot of all the vehicles in Washington as it includes a longitude and latitude in the CSV. Originally it came as one string value but I have separated the data and converted them to floats for the map. When testing I have confirmed that when using .dtypes it says my values are floats and I do not get any errors while running it. It's worth it to note the file is over 153k entires and about 20 mb. My main question is why when I use the default code from plotyl's website it displays the map but when trying my own code it displays a blank browser page.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio
os.chdir('/Users/dylandeforrest/cs projects/')
wash_df = pd.read_csv('Electric_Vehicle_Population_Data.csv')
#Loading in my data set
pio.renderers.default = 'browser'
unwanted = ["VIN (1-10)", "State", "Clean Alternative Fuel Vehicle (CAFV) Eligibility",  "Electric Range", "Base MSRP", "DOL Vehicle ID", "Electric Utility", "2020 Census Tract"]

for i in unwanted:
    del wash_df[i]
wash_df = wash_df.dropna()

wash_df[['point','Latt', 'Long']] = wash_df['Vehicle Location'].str.split(' ', expand=True)
del wash_df['point']

wash_df['Latt'] = wash_df['Latt'].str[1:]
wash_df['Long'] = wash_df['Long'].str[:-1]
wash_df['Latt'] = wash_df.Latt.astype(float)
wash_df['Long'] = wash_df.Long.astype(float)

fig = px.scatter_mapbox(wash_df, lat="Latt", lon="Long", hover_name="Make",zoom=3, height=300)

fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map")
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

This is what I have so far. I dont get any errors and it says my data type for the Latt and Long are both float64. What am I missing?

original file: https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/electric-vehicle-population-data

Comment: Welcome. Make it easier for us: in the spirit of [ask], especially [mre], please trim your code to the essentials. Starting with: remove the read_csv and loading business that we cannot do and replace it with a mock-up of the data that you submit to plotting, as text. e.g. posted as the output of `print(df.head().to_dict())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the issue with my CS teacher after investigating the blank window it gave an error that indicated that my Latt and Long were switched. I can now plot my points.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).